# Dynamic inilne style with default StyleSheet React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, flux

I need to give dynamic inline style with static default stylesheet style. How can I achieve this

```
<View 
    style={[styles.card,{{width:width,  height: height}}]}>
             <View style={styles.card}>
                <Text>
                  <Image
                    source={{uri: this.props.media.image_url}}
                    style={{width:width,  height: this.props.media.height}}/>
                </Text>
             </View>
 </View>
```

Above code is not working for me.

Comment: if you will go for server rendering you may have to change things in future because style loader is not supported by server rendering

Comment: what can be the solution for server rendering?

Comment: use https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin this will combine all css in one file.

Comment: This is React Native, server rendering is not a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the problem isn't the order, you haven't passed the dynamic(inline styles) properly. You wrapped them in additional curly braces

Change this:

```
style={[styles.card,{{width:width,  height: height}}]}
```

to:

```
style={[styles.card,{width:width,  height: height}]}
```

You have actually done the same thing in your answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after trying a lot I am able to resolve it.
Here is the code

```
  <View 
    <View style={[{width:width,  height: height},styles.card]}>
         <View style={styles.card}>
            <Text>
              <Image
                source={{uri: this.props.media.image_url}}
                style={{width:width,  height: this.props.media.height}}/>
            </Text>
         </View>
    </View>
 </View>
```

Comment: To clarify the solution: The order of the styles *do* matter, they're applied left to right, so `styles.card` overrides the width and height.